# Securing IPC loopback (localhost) access from third party desktop applications to self-hosted OWIN-based ASP.NET Web API 2 and SignalR desktop app

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, signalr, ipc

I would like to secure access to a ASP.NET Web API 2 as well as SignalR hubs both exposed using a self-hosted OWIN app hosted by a WPF desktop application. The WPF application is currently binding the OWIN HTTP listener to a TCP port on localhost for now, i.e it is not accessible from other machines.

The intention is that only my own other desktop applications as well as other third party desktop applications trusted by the end user (all running on the same end user machine as the WPF application) should be able to access the the Web API and SignalR hubs.

My current thought is to require the client application to authenticate with the WPF application, perhaps using a OWIN Authorization server (hosted by the WPF-application process) and a OAuth2 Client credentials flow where the WPF application would store the client credentials (client id and a salted password hash) in e.g., a settings file of the WPF application.

I have realised that since both the WPF application and all client desktop applications accessing it's Web API and SignalR hubs all run on the end user machine there is no point in attempting to "hide" any credentials used between the applications from the user. Since any encrypted password would need to be stored on the end user machine the desktop client applications may just as well use some security library or the underlying OS facilities to store an encrypted password knowing that the end user would be able to access it.

I have a few questions related to this.

1. Am I on the right track using OAuth2 Client credentials flow at all or is it inherently insecure when used for IPC on the same (end user) machine via the loopback interface?
2. With the realisation that the end user at least in theory have access to the credentials of a client desktop application and the end user could be a malicious user I have understood that in order to limit any damage done by a malicious end user only to that particular installation the same password for a specific client id should not be used in any two end user installations of the WPF application.
   If the same password would be used a malicious end user A could install client desktop application with client ID X, reverse engineer it to retrieve the password stored by it, write his/her own malicious application Y tricking victim end user B to run the malicious application Y which would then impersonate client ID X using the same password to authenticate with the WPF application running on victim end user B machine.

Given that each client id must have a unique password for each end user installation of the WPF application I would still like to keep the establishment of trust between the applications as transparent as possible to the end user. 
Any advice on this point would be very appreciated.
I.e., the less amount of steps needed by the end user to generate the password for an installed desktop client application and register the client id and password in the WPF application the better.

3. If OAuth2 is inappropriate for securing loopback (localhost) access to the ASP.NET Web API 2 and SignalR hubs. What would be the alternative?

Thanks

/John